# SymPy : Factorisation of a simple expression "a1*a2+a1*a3+a1*a4+a4*a2"

Tags: python, boolean, logic, sympy

I want to factorize/simply this expression f = "a1*a2+a1*a3+a1*a4+a4*a2" to a1*(a2+a3)+a4*(a1+a2) for example (minimize number of operators).

I use sympy to do so :

```
import sympy
a1,a2,a3,a4 = sympy.symbols('a1 a2 a3 a4')
f = "a1*a2+a1*a3+a1*a4+a4*a2"
sympy.init_printing(use_unicode=True)
sympy.simplify(f, deep=True,gaussian = True)
```

I got this 'a1*a2 + a1*a3 + a1*a4 + a2*a4' (even with sympy.simplify)

Do you know how I can get the result expected ?

Thank you !

Comment: `sympy.horner(f)` would give `a1*(a2 + a3 + a4) + a2*a4`. Or `sympy.horner(f, wrt=(a4, a1))` for `a1*(a2 + a3) + a4*(a1 + a2)`.   In general, sympy's `simplify` doesn't seem to consider this kind of rewriting.

Comment: Note that the preferred way to work with sympy is not via strings, but directly using the variables: `f = a1*a2+a1*a3+a1*a4+a4*a2`. Strings are useful when the input is read in from a file or so. Directly writing the variables gives less ambiguity (except with fractions as Python can change them to floats before sympy gets its hands on them).